# Disable selected option in other selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make all chosen options disabled in all three options? Its only working when the first one is selected.

```js
$(".selectClass").change(function() {
  $("select option").prop("disabled", false);
  $(".selectClass").not($(this)).find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectClass">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select class="selectClass">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select class="selectClass">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84w50z2v/1/

Comment: you are talking about the initial "state"? this is quite easy to achieve by adding `disabled` to the html elements. Updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/84w50z2v/2/

Comment: For future reference, please place all code within your question. People should not have to go off-site to understand what you're asking. I've edited your question for you in this case.

Comment: Thanks Rory! 

Thats not extactly what I mean. There are three options and when the first option is selected it's supposed to be disabled in the others options. The same goes for Option 2 and Option 3.

I want every already selected option to be disabled in the remaining option fields :) So that every Option can only be selected once.

Answer (score 2):

So far i understood you correctly you just need to set `disabled` to the HTML elements.

your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/84w50z2v/2/

```
<select class="selectClass">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select class="selectClass">
 <option value="1" disabled>1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select class="selectClass">
 <option value="1" disabled>1</option>
 ...
```

greetings

Answer (score 0):

For really disabling in all 3 option lists, you need to use this-

```
var selectedValues = [];
$(".selectClass").change(function () {
    selectedValues.push($(this).val());
    $.each(selectedValues,function(i,el){
        $(".selectClass").not($(this)).find("option[value='" + el + "']").prop("disabled", true);
    });
});
```

Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darshanTheerth/oywtwekx/).